# open same view controller with different data

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, viewcontroller

i have one problem i hope someone can help, im try to create an app like catalog, in the first view i have a table view with "x" number of items, this tableview is only an image of product, and then when you click on cell (image) the app send to you to another view, that view is the detail of the item.
worth mentioning that in the view controller is the table where I create a `NSMutableArray` with all products, then when you go to open the following view I do using the following code:

```
viewController cakeViewController * = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "ViewController"];

UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: viewController];

viewController.selectCake = [_cake objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
[self presentViewController: navigationController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

and works but in the second view i try to put a suggestion cake with img and when click image refresh or reload the view but with the data of the suggested cake.
thanks a lot!

Comment: You're on the right track when you're doing .selectCake before presenting the NavigationController. What is your exact issue?

Comment: What's this: viewController cakeViewController * = ???

Comment: LyricalPanda i need add 2 suggestion buttons and when click on this buttons open same view but with the data of the item selected.